# Is there a constant something like bits_in_byte (8)?

Tags: c++, c, byte, constants, bit

Is there in C/C++ standart constant that reflects how many bits are there in one byte (8)? Something like CHAR_BIT but for byte.

Comment: That is what `CHAR_BIT` tells you. A char is a byte.

Comment: I think the sensible approach is to assume that a byte is 8 bits. Because then your programs will crash on systems where it is not: a suitable punishment for people using such systems.

Comment: Or use `static_assert(8 == CHAR_BIT);` Just trundling along is a security problem waiting to happen.

Comment: @Simple While the C Standard does not define if a byte has to be an octet, POSIX does require a byte to be an octet, it's therefore very unlikely you'll encounter a situation where this isn't true (exclude embedded, where this is actually true in some cases).

Comment: @Brans Ds A byte is **not** 8 bits. An octet is 8 bits. A byte can also be 4 bits, or 16 bits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the C standard, a `char` is one byte. Therefore `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a byte.

The C standard says that `CHAR_BIT` is *"number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)"*.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof()` operator is consistent with `CHAR_BIT` constant defined in `<climits>` header, see the *Notes* section: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

> Depending on the computer architecture, a byte may consist of 8 or
> more bits, the exact number being recorded in CHAR_BIT.

Above documentation defines the byte and its bits count.

Also some implementations of `std::bitset` use `CHAR_BIT` to obtain bits per byte.